# Shutdown EC2 instances that do not have a certain tag using Python

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, tags, boto3

I'm using this script by mlapida posted here: 
https://gist.github.com/mlapida/1917b5db84b76b1d1d55#file-ec2-stopped-tagged-lambda-py

The script by mlapida does the opposite of what I need, I'm not that familiar with Python to know how to restructure it to make this work.  I need to shutdown all EC2 instances that do not have a special tag identifying them.

The logic would be: 
1.) Identify all running instances
2.) Strip out any instances from that list that have the special tag
3.) Process the remaining list of instances to be shutdown

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

That's should do the trick:

```
# open connection to ec2
conn = get_ec2_conn()
# get a list of all instances
all_instances = conn.get_all_instances()
# get instances with filter of running + with tag `Name`
instances = conn.get_all_instances(filters={'tag-key': 'Name', 'instance-state-name': 'running'})
# make a list of filtered instances IDs `[i.id for i in instances]`
# Filter from all instances the instance that are not in the filtered list
instances_to_delete = [to_del for to_del in all_instances if to_del.id not in [i.id for i in instances]]
# run over your `instances_to_delete` list and terminate each one of them
for instance in instances_to_delete:
    conn.stop_instances(instance.id)
```

And in boto3:

```
# open connection to ec2
conn = get_ec2_conn()
# get a list of all instances
all_instances = [i for i in conn.instances.all()]
# get instances with filter of running + with tag `Name`
instances = [i for i in conn.instances.filter(Filters=[{'Name': 'instance-state-name', 'Values': ['running']}, {'Name':'tag-key', 'Values':['Name']}])]
# make a list of filtered instances IDs `[i.id for i in instances]`
# Filter from all instances the instance that are not in the filtered list
instances_to_delete = [to_del for to_del in all_instances if to_del.id not in [i.id for i in instances]]
# run over your `instances_to_delete` list and terminate each one of them
for instance in instances_to_delete:
    instance.stop()
```

Comment: I'm using AWS Lambda which only supports boto3, how would you recommend it be written in the context of boto3 and Python 2.7?

Comment: Look at my update, It's kind of hacky but it's my first shot with boto3 but it's working :) @TimHolm

Comment: Also I would try to read Amazon's docs http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/guide/migrationec2.html#checking-what-instances-are-running

Answer (score 1):

With credits to mlapida and Yonatan, I have a working script that shuts down all instances that don't have a tag "AutoOff" and any instance that does have "AutoOff" set to "False" stays on, hope this helps someone out there.

```
import boto3
import logging

#setup simple logging for INFO
logger = logging.getLogger()
logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)

#define the connection
ec2 = boto3.resource('ec2')
# open connection to ec2
#conn = get_ec2_conn()

# get a list of all instances
all_instances = [i for i in ec2.instances.all()]

def lambda_handler(event, context):

    #instances = ec2.instances.filter(Filters=filters)
    # get instances with filter of running + with tag `Name`
    instances = [i for i in ec2.instances.filter(Filters=[{'Name': 'instance-state-name', 'Values': ['running']}, {'Name':'tag:AutoOff', 'Values':['False']}])]

    # make a list of filtered instances IDs `[i.id for i in instances]`
    # Filter from all instances the instance that are not in the filtered list
    instances_to_delete = [to_del for to_del in all_instances if to_del.id not in [i.id for i in instances]]

    # run over your `instances_to_delete` list and terminate each one of them
    for instance in instances_to_delete:
        instance.stop()
```