# How to create an AWS policy which allows the instances to launch only if it has tags created?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ansible

How to create an AWS policy which can restrict the users to create an instance unless they create tags while they try to launch the instance?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: I just want to create a policy that would not allow my users to create an instance unless they follow the tagging strategy.which was defined

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible using an IAM policy alone. The reason being that all EC2 instances are launched without EC2 tags. Tags are added to the EC2 instance after it has launched.

The AWS Management Console hides this from you, but it's a two-step process.

The best you can do is to stop and/or terminate your EC2 instances after-the-fact if they are missing the tags.

Comment: [cue some Monkey](https://medium.com/netflix-techblog/the-netflix-simian-army-16e57fbab116)..

Comment: Can you please share the code or policy fro stop / terminate the instance if they are missing the tags

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38085482/shutdown-ec2-instances-that-do-not-have-a-certain-tag-using-python

Comment: Earlier this year, AWS made some changes in this area. You can now tag an instance on EC2 launch in a single, atomic operation and you can therefore write IAM polices requiring tags at launch. See https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-tag-ec2-instances-ebs-volumes-on-creation/.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to recent AWS changes, you can launch an EC2 instance and apply tags, all in a single, atomic operation. You can therefore write IAM polices requiring tags at launch.

More details, and a sample IAM policy, can be found at the [AWS blog post announcing the changes](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-tag-ec2-instances-ebs-volumes-on-creation/).