# BOTO3 : How to filter instance with tag "not equal" to something?

Tags: filter, tags, boto3

we can find a lot fo examples regarding ec2 filtering wit boto3.
But I'm lookiing for a solution to list all instances EXCEPTED those with a specific tag...

how is it possible?

Many thanks

Comment: It looks like Boto3 [does not support exclude filters](https://github.com/boto/boto3/issues/173).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Auto-answering (if it could be usefull for other... or be optimized :))

```
import boto3
import logging

#define client connection
ec2c = boto3.client('ec2')
#define ressources connection
#ec2r = boto3.resource('ec2')

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    global ec2c
    global ec2r

    # Get list of regions
    regionslist = ec2c.describe_regions().get('Regions',[] )

    # Iterate over regions
    for region in regionslist:
        print("=================================\n\n")
        print ("Looking at region %s " % region['RegionName'])
        reg=region['RegionName']

        # Connect to region
        #ec2r = boto3.setup_default_session(region_name=reg)
        ec2r = boto3.resource('ec2', region_name=reg)

        # get a list of all instances
        all_running_instances = [i for i in ec2r.instances.filter(Filters=[{'Name': 'instance-state-name', 'Values': ['running']}])]
        for instance in all_running_instances:
            print("Running instance : %s" % instance.id)

        # get instances with filter of running + with tag `Name`
        instances = [i for i in ec2r.instances.filter(Filters=[{'Name': 'instance-state-name', 'Values': ['running']}, {'Name':'tag:KeepMeAlive', 'Values':['Yes']}])]
        for instance in instances:
            print("Running instance with tag : %s" % instance.id)

        # make a list of filtered instances IDs `[i.id for i in instances]`
        # Filter from all instances the instance that are not in the filtered list
        instances_to_delete = [to_del for to_del in all_running_instances if to_del.id not in [i.id for i in instances]]

        # run over your `instances_to_delete` list and terminate each one of them
        for instance in instances_to_delete:
            instance.stop()
            print("Instance : %s stopped" % instance.id)
        print("=================================\n\n")
```

Answer (score 0):

I just found this one : [Shutdown EC2 instances that do not have a certain tag using Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38085482/shutdown-ec2-instances-that-do-not-have-a-certain-tag-using-python)

But I forgot to precise that I would like to do it cross regions.
I suppose I need to use boto3.client & boto3.resource but I don't understand how to do this.